# Bootstrap: image height decrease while resizing window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The issue i am facing is , I have 2 columns.
1 : **image**
2 : **panel**

when I resize my browser window, the image height is decreasing compare to panel.

[image: Image height is decreasing]

[image: Original View]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <a target="_blank" href="">
                            <div class="theme_view">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="">
                                
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                        <div class="panel panel-default set_padding_0 set_margin_0" >
                            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                                 <span class="font_size_14">Theme Name</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="radio">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="radio">
                                            <label class="i-checks">
                                                <input value="option2" checked="" disabled="" type="radio">
                                                <i></i>
                                                Personal Domain Name
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Where m I lacking?

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: you have a class `img-responsive` and thats the normal behavior of it,

Comment: yes.. but i want image height and panel height to be same while resizing window. how can i do so?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
You can specify heigh what you want

```
<img class="image" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="">


.image {
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; // here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create a element and set class "container" for that and put both div into it :
.container set width fixed for elements

.try this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
               <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <a target="_blank" href="">
                            <div class="theme_view">
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/ img_fjords.jpg"alt=""> 

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                        <div class="panel panel-default set_padding_0 set_margin_0" >
                            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                                 <span class="font_size_14">Theme Name</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="radio">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="radio">
                                            <label class="i-checks">
                                                <input value="option2" checked="" disabled="" type="radio">
                                                <i></i>
                                                Personal Domain Name
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```